# Wordpress with WooCommerce on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've launched my wordpress site on beanstalk and everything works great, however every time I re-deploy the site using beanstalk I need to go the admin page in wordpress and deactivate and active the WooCommerce plugin in order for the WooCommerce pages to be visible again (otherwise I start getting 404s everytime I go to cart or any other WooCommerce page).  I am using the StoreFront template with only CSS changes.  I have installed the AWS Services and S3 plugin for uploads.  I have using Aurora DB for my database so that never changes or goes away. What am I missing here?  I've checked the DB and all the WooCommerce_*_page_id values are set.  Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solved it!  WordPress was writing out it's .htaccess file... just so happens the main page wasn't affected by this and only the woocommerce pages where... added that to my zip... beanstalk deploy works like a charm now!